# Can a label defined inside a try block be accessed in the catch block?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, label

```
try {
            do {
                input: if (choice2 != null)
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
                choice2 = reader.readLine();
            } while ((int) choice2.charAt(0) >= 65 && (int) choice2.charAt(0) <= 69);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            continue input;
        }
```

Is there anyway to implement a similar functionality? The above code is an example.

Comment: You should not use exceptions for flow control.  Remove the try/catch and just do `while (choice2 == null || choice2.isEmpty() || !(choice2.charAt(0) >= 65 && choice2.charAt(0) <= 69))`.  The `||` and `&&` are short circuit operators, so if choice2 is null or empty, the charAt part will not execute.  (I assume you consider 'A'–'E' valid choices.)

Comment: I know this can be achieved through a single while loop. But for some reason, my trainer has asked me to do it in this way and also handle the exception of when the use does not inputs anything and presses enter.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `try-catch` into the **loop *body***. And you probably meant to label the loop. And, even though they're optional, use braces. Like,

```
input: do {
    try {
        if (choice2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
        }
        choice2 = reader.readLine();
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        continue input;
    }
} while ((int) choice2.charAt(0) >= 65 && (int) choice2.charAt(0) <= 69);
```